# insertAfter() is duplicating an element when I don't want it to

Tags: javascript, dom

Okay, so I'm making a chatbot, and I ran into a problem.  So I need to make a function that creates a chat message everytime the enter key is pressed.  So far, it's coming out nicely, just one problem.  It's duplicating an element, that I only want one of.

To see what I'm talking about, go to http://jsfiddle.net/MatthewKosloski/BHXMa/ and type out a message, then hit enter.  Notice how there are two "Foo!" messages?  I only want one.  I'd also want to make these messages go from top-bottom in chronological order, but I can't do that until I find out why this duplication is occuring!

```
function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

var robotMessage = userMessage;

function intelResponse(){

        // ROBOT
        var robot = document.createElement("h4");
        var robotText = document.createTextNode("Robot");
        robot.appendChild(robotText);
        robot.className = "rtitle";
        document.body.appendChild(robot);
        insertAfter(userMessage, robot);

        // Robot's response
        robotMessage = document.createElement("span");
        var robotMessageText = document.createTextNode("FOO");
        robotMessage.appendChild(robotMessageText);
        robotMessage.className = "rmsg";
        document.body.appendChild(robotMessage);
        insertAfter(robot, robotMessage);

}
```

Comment: That's because you are calling `intelResponse` twice. Once inside the event handler and once inside the `submitUserMessage` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple mistake . You are calling the method `intelResponse` twice. Fixed the issue[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/skyrbe/BHXMa/1/)

```
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        submitUserMessage();
        //intelResponse();
        $("#user-input").val("");
    }
```

Comment: @MattKnowsTech : It's always the smaller issues that get developers :D

Answer (score 1):

You're calling "intelResponse" from the "submit" routine, and also explicitly *after* you call the "submit" routine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies at the end of `submitUserResponse` function, where you also calling `intelResponse`

Answer (score 1):

The message is appending twice because you call the function twice.

One time on keyup:

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        submitUserMessage();
        intelResponse();
        $("#user-input").val("");
    }
});
```

And in the submitUserMessage.

Comment one of those and it doesnt duplicate: http://jsfiddle.net/BHXMa/2/